# Composing jpeg image with multiple png files in Erlang/Elixir

Tags: c, erlang, imagemagick, elixir, beam

I need to overlap a series of png images in order to create a single jpeg file in Erlang/Elixir.
I can't find anywhere a way to do this task on the BEAM, so I would love to use Erlang NIFs and writing down some C code using the ImageMagick APIs, but again I can't find any documentation for this task.

Is there a way to do this in Erlang/Elixir/C?

Comment: *"but again I can't find any documentation for this task*" Here's the documentation for an ImageMagick C API: https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php Here's the documentation for NIFs: http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

- Use ImageMagick CLI - easy, slowest, safe (separate process)
- Write port wrapper using library bindings in your prefered [language](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/develop.php) (C, Perl, LUA, Python, ...) - harder, fast, safe (separate process)
- Use NIFs - even harder, fastest (if done right!), unsafe (compromise BEAM reliability)

Choose according to your skill and requirements! If you are unable even found [NIF official documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) and [MagickWand API documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php) I have some doubts the last one is the best choice for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. In that case I need very high performances, so I think I'll try with NIFs. Thanks!

Comment: Now, an example of each would be nice--perhaps with some easier task?